# Different ports with local sever and webpack dev mode and "the string does not match the expected pattern error "

Tags: javascript, api, webpack

I am trying to build a project with webpack using wikipedia api.
I make a GET request from my server using express.
I used route params to send the user search input.
This is what I have set in my server.js

```
app.get('/getInput/:searchTerm', async function(req,res){
const userInput = req.params.searchTerm
const url =`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=${userInput}`
const data = await fetch (url)

try{
    const json = await data.json()
    res.send(json)
    console.log("Json Data got", json.query.search[1].title)
    
}
catch(error){
    console.log("You got error:",error)
}
```

This is the code from client side

```
export const handleSubmit = async (search)=>{
console.log(search)

//const url = `/getInput`
const url = `/getInput/${search}`
console.log(url)
const data = await fetch (url)

try{
     const json = data.json()
     console.log(json)
}
catch(err){
    console.log("Error in client side", err)
}
```

}

This is the btn in my html

```
<button onclick="return Client.handleSubmit('water')"
```

When click the btn, it triggers the GET request, but I got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "the string does not match the expected pattern" errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Atc.png)

There are few things I am confusing about:

1. Am I doing right in my client side for grabbing the response sent back from my server?
2. My express server is listening at port 8087, but my dev mode is using 8080. Which port should I go to try out my code?

Sorry I am quite new with webpack, I appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.